# In which Table errors and warnings are stored in AX 2012 r3

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I want to know the tables where the Standard errors and warnings are stored in Microsoft Dynamics Ax 2012 R3.

Comment: Do you mean the messages you receive in the infolog? These are not stored, except in some cases (e.g. batch jobs). Or do you want to know the code that triggers these messages?

Comment: Okay, I was referring to the messages shown in the infolog.